# YII 1 grid search is not working

Tags: php, yii

I am beginner in YII 1 and i am trying to use grid search in my YII application but my grid search is not working.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

viewSurveyList.php

```
<?php $this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Survey Data'; ?>
<div id="innercontent" style="padding-top:30px;">
<h1><?php echo SURVEYLISTHEADTITLE; ?></h1>
<div class="row-button-right">
 <?php echo CHtml::button('New Survey',array('type'=>'submit','submit'=>array('site/createSurvey')));?>
</div>

<?php

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'servey-list',
    'dataProvider' => $modelSurvey->search(),      
    'filter' => $modelSurvey,
    'pager'=>array('header'=>'','prevPageLabel'=>'Previous','nextPageLabel'=>'Next','maxButtonCount'=>SHOWNUMBEROFPAGENUMBER ),
    'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination',      
    'emptyText'=>'No Survey Found',
    'template' => "{items}\n{summary}\n{pager}",
    'columns'=>array(   
        array(
            'header'=>'Name',     
            'name'=>'Name',     
            'value' => '$data->Name',
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'80%','valign'=>'middle','align'=>'center'),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'80%','valign'=>'top','align'=>'left'),
            'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($modelSurvey,'Name',array('placeholder'=>'Survey Name')),
        ),  


        array(
            'header'=>'Action', 
            'name'=>'Action',
            'value' => function($data){ echo Survey::model()->getActionLink($data); },
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'20%','valign'=>'middle','align'=>'center'),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'20%','valign'=>'top','align'=>'left'),
            'filter'=>CHtml::link('Clear Filters',array('site/surveyList'),array('title'=>'Clear Filters')),
        ),          
    ),  
));


 ?>
 </div>
```

Model Survey.php

```
 public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
    print_r($this); 
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);
    $criteria->compare('Name',$this->Name,true);
    //$criteria->compare('IsDeleted',$this->IsDeleted);
    $criteria->compare('CreatedOn',$this->CreatedOn,true);
    $criteria->compare('LastModifiedOn',$this->LastModifiedOn,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'Pagination' => array('pageSize'=>SETTINGPAGESIZE), // number of rows per page setting
    ));
}
 public function rules()
{       
        // The following rule is used by search().
    return array(   
        array('ID, Name, CreatedOn, LastModifiedOn,QuestionNumbers', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Action call from SiteController.php

```
public function actionSurveyList()
{           
   $modelSurvey = new Survey('search');
   $this->render('viewSurveyList',array('modelSurvey'=>$modelSurvey));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below code in your actionSurveyList method

```
public function actionSurveyList(){     

    $modelSurvey = new Survey('search');

    if(isset($_GET['Survey']))
        $modelSurvey->attributes=$_GET['Survey'];

    $this->render('viewSurveyList',array('modelSurvey'=>$modelSurvey));

}
```